# Facebook multi-friend-selector gets cut off in iframe

Tags: php, facebook, xfbml

I've been working on a Facebook app and the only thing that's still bogging me down is the friend requests.

When I use the fb:multi-friend-selector code, the confirmation pop-up gets cut off by the iframe on the right hand side. The app is an iframe-based canvas app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a **width** attribute on the `<fb:serverfbml>` tag to make it wide enough:

```
<fb:serverfbml width="615">
  <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:request-form ...></fb:request-form>
  </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Example: http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector

EDIT: Made it more of an answer.

Comment: yep, serverfbml width was the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a note (this answer fixed my problem!!) the Facebook Developer documentation on fb:serverFbml is not correct. It says to use <fb:serverFbml style="width: 600px;"> to set the width, but this doesn't work correctly! You need to use <fb:serverfbml width = "600">

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, that is actually a problem with Facebook itself.

Where the iFrame should be Dynamically resizing with the content but only dynamically resizes to the content on load rather than when the content changes.

Comment: Not at least from Facebook, but you could try using Javascript to resize the iFrame yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Also having a problem with this. In this example, not only are they getting the popup to display over top everything, but the selector itself is not even in an iframe. How are they doing this?

http://apps.facebook.com/sharethejoy/invite.php